# How to redirect the user to a page using AuthenticationSuccessHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

I implemented a success handler that will redirect a user to a certain page if he or she is an admin user.

```
public class MaunaKeaAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  private static final RedirectStrategy REDIRECT_STRATEGY = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (isMkeaAdmin(authentication)) {
      REDIRECT_STRATEGY.sendRedirect(request, response, "/admin/submission-queue.html");
    }
  }

  private static boolean isMkeaAdmin(Authentication authentication) {
    if (!(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof AccountUserDetailsAdapter)) {
      return false;
    }
    AccountUserDetailsAdapter userDetails = (AccountUserDetailsAdapter) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return userDetails.getAccount().getRoles().contains("MKEA_Admin");
  }

}
```

The `onAuthenticationSuccess` method gets called, and the `sendRedirect` method gets called too. But the user does not get redirected. Instead, he or she gets sent to the default page, `/index.html`, thanks to the `index` method in my controller.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('PERM_CAN_LOGIN')")
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html")
public String index(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    WebUtils.activeNav(NAV_HOME);
    return viewRegistry.getPath("main.index");
}
```

Here is part of my `spring-security.xml`.

```
<beans:bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter"
  p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager">
  <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:bean class="gov.ehawaii.maunakea.security.MaunaKeaAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
  </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

How do I implement the redirect so that the `index` method in my controller does not get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already provided the request context in your redirection url.You need to set contextRelative = true in your redirection strategy so that it ignore the request context in final redirection url.

```
DefaultRedirectStrategy REDIRECT_STRATEGY = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
REDIRECT_STRATEGY.setContextRelative(true);
```